# How do I force compaction to eliminate stopped writes?

Tags: rocksdb

How do I force compaction to eliminate stopped writes ?

Writes to my db stopped due to following error:

```
Stopping writes because we have 36 level-0 files
```

Here is full log
https://hastebin.com/raw/odunajuxap

I tried to increase `max_background_compactions` and `write_buffer_size` but nothing happens.

I also tried to call `compactRange()`. It's blocking call but I don't see indication of activity in the log.

And I couldn't use Ldb Tool to compact because I use custom comparator.

What should I do ?